# Intuition behind the fundamental group $\pi_1(S^1)$

Tags: general-topology, geometry, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

I have gone over the fact that $\pi_1(S^1) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ and its proof, though I admittedly do not understand it in full. What I am struggling with is the intuition behind this fact, since as I understand it, every integer $n$ can be thought of as how many revolutions we make around the circle. However in view of the intuition behind homotopy and deformations, regardless of how many times we loop through the circle, is the deformation not going to be the same, that is, result in $S^1$? How then do different $n$ represent distinct homotopy classes?

Comment: That depends _entirely_ on what kind of deformations we allow. Have you looked at the exact definition of the deformations that $\pi_1$ allows?

Comment: The crucial point here is that the deformation of the loop to a point must take place entirely within $S^1$. You cannot use the interior of the unit ball to deform the loop to a point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the key to your misunderstanding is that a "loop" in $S^1$ in the definition of the fundamental group is a *function* $l:[0,1]\to S^1$, not a *subset* of $S^1$. This is quite a subtle point, but absolutely crucial. If a loop was defined as a sunset (in particular as the image of the function $l$, what is normally referred to as the *trace* of $l$) then you would be right, a loop which goes around $S^1$ once is exactly the same as a loop which goes around it a million times. However, a *function* which wraps $[0,1]$ around $S^1$ is completely different to a *function* which wraps $[0,1]$ around $S^1$ a million times.

Let's be concrete to illustrate this. Identify $S^1$ with the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$ and define $l_1:[0,1]\to S^1:t\mapsto e^{2\pi i t}$, and define $l_2:[0,1]\to S^1:t\mapsto e^{2\pi i (2t)}$. These both trace out $S^1$, so their images are equal as sets. However, at $t=1/2$ for example, $l_1(1/2)=-1$, while $l_2(1/2)=1$, so these are different as functions. In particular we can think of $l_1$ as representing $1$ in $\pi_1(S^1)$, and $l_2$ as representing $2$.

Comment: Ahh I see, so thinking of $t$ as representing time, we can say that the speed of the loop distinguishes loops. Would that be correct?

Comment: @CBBAM It would be more correct to say that the number of laps distinguishes the loops. So average speed is much better than just speed.

Comment: I kind of see where you're going with your intuition here, but one has to be careful, because I could reparametrize the loop so that I travelled really slowly for the first 0.999 seconds covering very little distance and then speed up to go round the loop 2 times in the final 0.0001 seconds. This would give a different function $l_2'$, and hence a different loop to $l_2$, but these two loops would be homotopic, and so represent the same element of $\pi_1(S^1)$.

Comment: @Arthur exactly, I think between our comments we cover it

Comment: That helps a lot, thanks! The only point I am still stuck on is the notion of homotopy itself. I thought I had understood it but after your comment I believe I may not. I was under the impression that, informally speaking, the only two things that matter for two functions to be homotopic are the end points and if the loops get "stuck" on the same things. With multiple revolutions how are either of these violated?

Comment: You are right, two loops are the same if they are homotopic "relative to the basepoint", ie homotopic without moving the basepoint. Here's an intuitive picture. Replace the circle with the wheel in a pulley, then you can think of a loop $l:[0,1]\to S^1$ as taking a piece of string 1 foot long and wrapping it around the pulley some number of times. Now glue the endpoints of the string to the same point on the pulley. The homotopies you can perform are exactly the manipulations of the string without taking the string off the pulley and manipulating it in 3 dimensions.

Comment: Can you see that you cannot change the number of times the string is wrapped around the pulley by a homotopy?

Comment: CBBAM : do you understand why the loop that goes once around $S^1$ isn't homotopic to the identity? What's it getting 'stuck' on? That's exactly what happens between one loop and two, or between five loops and twenty-three — they're 'stuck' in that there's no continuous deformation from one mapping to the other. You can think of it as being like winding  rope around a post; you can add kinks in the rope, change how it folds back on itself, but in the end you can't change how many times the rope winds around the post without some sort of 'unhitch'.

Comment: @DavidSheard Ah yes, thank you for that picture! So the number of laps cannot be changed under homotopy, only the "shape" of each loop can?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Yes I think that makes sense now! So you cannot go from $n$ loops to $m$ loop for $n \neq m$ by simple deformations, as they're all getting "stuck" by the circle itself?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right @CBBAM

Comment: @DavidSheard Thank you for guiding me!

Answer (score 0):

This, I think, is quite a non-standard way of looking at this but I think it might help visualise why these loops are fundamentally different.

Split $S^1$ in half at the base point to form the unit line $[0,1]$, with the basepoint corresponding to $0$ and $1$. For ease lets assume that any loop in $S^1$ corresponds to starting at $0$ in $[0,1]$. Then a loop in $S^1$ that goes around just once is a path in $[0,1]$ that starts at $0$ and ends at $1$. A loop that goes around $S^1$ twice starts at $0$, goes to $1$ and then reappears at $0$ and continues to $1$. There is clearly no way to construct a homotopy that makes a "reappearing" loop into one that doesn't at all. For the "negative" loops in $S^1$ you can use the same argument but with the path starting at $1$ instead.

Like I said this reasoning is not standard and not at all precise, but I think it illustrates in some sense the differences between the homotopy classes in $S^1$.

Comment: I don't think "bouncing" is what you meant to say. Such a loop would backtrack in $S^1$ and so be null-homotopic. A loop which goes round $S^1$ twice would go from $0$ to $1$, then teleport back to $0$ and again move to $1$.

Comment: @DavidSheard That's a good point actually! Will edit my answer. Thanks for the correction.